# error when setting PostCodeGenCommand for a simulink model

Tags: code-generation, simulink

I would like to add a post-build hook to my code generation process. However, when I try to associate a function with the simulink model's PostCodeGenCommand, I get the following error.

```
set_param(bdroot, 'PostCodeGenCommand', 'packNGo(buildInfo);')
A configuration set reference does not allow writing to parameters in the source configuration set
```

I don't really understand the error message, and it doesn't bring up any useful hits on my favourite search engine. Can anyone help me decipher it?

Unfortunately, I could not reproduce this problem on a simple simulink model, even if I included a reference model. (I thought that might be what the word "reference" was, um, referencing in the error message. And I've noticed previously that referenced models are handled differently to other models in the simulink code generator.)

I'm using R2015a, but have access to the newer versions if that would help.

Note that this question was originally posted on the [Matlab forum](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/345475#946188), but didn't get any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the model was using a "configuration reference" rather than storing its configuration internally. The Model Explorer provides the following description

```
Configuration Reference
A model may reference a 'Configuration set' that is defined in the 
source location rather than stored in the model....
```

This is useful for us because we use several models which all share the same configuration set. It's saved in a central place and all updates apply immediately to all models.

The side effect is that `bdroot` no longer has a `PostCodeGenCommand` associated with it. Instead, the command I was looking for was

```
configurationSettings.set_param('PostCodeGenCommand', 'packNGo(buildInfo);')
```

where `configurationSettings` is a variable in your workspace, and the variable's name should match the "Referenced configuration set name" in the Model Explorer.